# Deck of Cards java project with confusion on intertwining a for loop and toString method

Tags: java, for-loop, tostring

//** The code below is broken up into 2 classes and 2 Enums respectively: Card, Deck, Suit and Rank.

I'm having confusion on intertwining a for loop and toString method as asked in the instructions:

Create a toString() method in the Deck class, using another for loop to print all the Cards in the array by calling the toString() method on each card. This method “asks” the Card to print its rank and suit by only calling toString() on the Card object. There should be no reference to Rank or Suit anywhere in this method. Let Card's toString() method do the work (Delegation).

```
public class Card {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Card myCard = new Card();
        System.out.println(myCard.toString());
        System.out.println(new Card(Rank.KING, Suit.CLUBS));
    }

    public Rank rank;

    public Suit suit;

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }   

    private void setRank(Rank rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    private void setSuit(Suit suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    // Constructor assigning attributes to rank and suit 
    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        setRank(rank);
        setSuit(suit);
    }

    public Card() {
        this(Rank.ACE, Suit.SPADES);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result= rank.toString() + &quot; of &quot; + suit.toString();

        return result;  }

}

public enum Suit {
    NONE, CLUBS, HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS
}

public enum Rank {
    JOKER, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN,
    KING, ACE
}

public class Deck {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        int[] DeckArray = new int[54];
        int count = 2;

        System.out.println(count);

        for (count = 0; count &lt;= 54; count++)
        {
            System.out.println(DeckArray);

        }

    }

    public Card cards[];

    public void DeckOfCards() {
        this.cards = new Card[52];
        Card myCard = new Card();

        for (int i = 0; i &lt; 0; i++) {
            Card card = new Card(Rank.ACE, Suit.CLUBS);

            if (Rank.JOKER != null) {
            System.out.println("JOKER");
        } else {
            System.out.println(myCard);

        }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    String Deck = Arrays.toString(DeckArray)


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful: `count <= 54` in `Deck` will cause an exception when `System.out.println(DeckArray[count]);` will be called with `count =54`. Btw you have to replace `System.out.println(DeckArray);` by `System.out.println(DeckArray[count]);`   And please format your code

Comment: What, exactly, are you wondering about? Can you be more specific about your confusion? Also, is this all your code? Nothing follows "if (Rank.JOKER)"

Comment: Please take care to format your question correctly, as it stands it is unreadable (especially the code).

Comment: @sjgp The code has been updated, and my confusion stems from correctly using another for loop to print all the Cards in the array. I just don't know what that looks like exactly.

Comment: @KojoByson it looks like the problem statement wants you to write a method toString() on the Deck class, that uses a for-loop to iterate over your DeckArray and calls the Card class's toString() method to print the details, rather than using Card's getRank() and getSuit() methods. So your main() or wherever would call Deck's toString() 1 time, not in a loop, and it would handle looping over every Card. Does this help clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this is Psudo-code so that I won't do your homework for you :)

```
class Deck {
    ...
    public String toString() {
        for every item in this.cards {
            currentItem.toString() // prints
        }
    }
}
```

Best of luck!  Once you get the hang of it programming can be really fun.

Comment: Great answer but I would use something between each printed item. A space or semicolon. Also toString() is not void.

Comment: Good catch Sedrick.  I've edited the original message with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original code shows some confusion over how to define the condition that ends the for-loop, you may prefer to use this idiom instead:

```
for ( Card c : cards ) {
   // do your work here
}
```

You can use the Java 8 Streams API, too, although in this case it feels unnecessarily complex:for-

```
Arrays.asList(cards).stream().forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.toString()));
```